# new Date возвращает неверное время и дату

Tags: java, android

вот что я получаю выполнив код в пол 2 ночи 29 октября 2017 года:

```
    I/System.out: текущая дата и время:  Thu Dec 28 17:34:33 EST 2017 
 libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",mRawOffset=-18000000,mEarliestRawOffset=-18000000,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=235]
```

отставание на 8 часов. 
 Метод

```
java.util.Locale.getDefault()
```

возвращает `us`

Так и должно быть, что дефолтная локаль us?

Выполняю на вин 7 , в эмуляторе андроид

Проверил на подключенном телефоне. Всё показывает верно. Вывод: проблемы с виндовс.  Вот здесь https://javatalks.ru/topics/44063 есть подобный вопрос. У меня java version "1.8.0_60"

Comment: `TimeZone.getDefault()` что выдаёт?

Comment: На винде раньше криво считывалась таймзона из регистра. Хз как сейчас. Лучше явно указывать таймзону при запуске `-Duser.timezone="Australia/Sydney"`

Comment: Вы не пробовали самостоятельно в эмуляторе выставить вашу таймзону?

Comment: Suvitruf, то что приложено в вопросе и есть результат функции TimeZone.getDefault() , а именно libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",mRawOffset=-18000000,mEarliestRawOffset=-18000000,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=235] . (подскажите как в комментарии код форматировать)

Comment: DeKaNszn, да , что то сразу не догадался. Тупо в эмуляторе убрал галочки Использовать время оператора. И выставил таймзону москвы и время вручную. Только локаль us осталась. Это правильно? я так понимаю если я в ресурсах не создал другие локали, то по умолчанию локаль us . Так?

Comment: @Turalllb, используйте `Locale.getDefault()`, тогда локаль будет браться из настроек устройства.

Comment: Будет браться? Так я это и делаю.  Он он не братья будет,  а возвращать.  В настройках ставлю таймзону москвы,  а этот метод все равно возвращает us